# Sitecore 8.1 WFFM RegEx validation message not working for MVC Layout, but working for Aspx layout

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

[image]

[image]

Hi All, i am using sitecore 8.1 update 1 with WFFM 8.1.rev. 151008
in my site from the above image as you can see i have defined reg ex validation message for age field, but in output on click submit the custom error message is not appearing instead its showing a different message as below 2nd image.

The same regex error mesage is working fine if i use aspx layout , please let me know is this a bug in sitecore or any other work around.

Comment: Right under that `Error Message` box there is a section called `Validation Error Messages (MVC)` with 3 field validation messages. Did you try setting those?

Comment: Below the error message section i can see only Minimum length and maximum length setting, but no section defining MVC Error messages inside the form editor

Comment: You should see the following fields which are used for MVC. If you don't, then something else is wrong: http://imgur.com/a/MTGt0

Comment: I guess it is not in 8.1 update 1.. In the release notes of 8.1 update 2: New features & improvements  New functionality has been added in Form Designer which lets you define custom error validation messages for MVC forms (70805, 67103) https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081%20Update2/Release%20Notes

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bluemink, so will the wffm update-2 package works on my sitecore 8.1 update 1 ?

Comment: If you want a supported config. No the version must match see https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/779556